# Stack implementation in python using jupyter

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, stack

This is my first program in Python: a stack implementation.

```
class Stack:
    items =[];
    index =-1;

    def isEmpty(self):
        return  self.index >=0;

    def push(self,item):
            self.index  +=1;
            print(self.index);
            self.items.insert(self.index,item);


    def pop(self):

        if self.index<0:
            raise Exception(" no items in list");
        else:    
            del self.items[self.index];
            self.index -=1;

    def peek(self):
        print(self.index);
        if self.index >-1:
            return self.items[self.index];



stackobj = Stack();
stackobj.push("solomon");
stackobj.push("helloworld")
stackobj.pop();

print(stackobj.peek())
```

Even though this program works I'm still confused as to whether I've written the program in the right way. I am also not sure when to use the `self` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the land of Python!

If you come from Java, think as `self` being the same as `this` in Java.
It is a reference to the object, the difference being in Python, you have to explicitly pass self as a parameter to the class methods.

If you write in Java

```
class Stack{

    //constructor and class variables goes here

    void pop(){
       if(this.index < 0)
       //logic of the function goes here
    }
}
```

In Python you write like you did here

```
class Stack:
    # constructor and class variables goes here

    def pop(self):
        if self.index<0:
        # logic of the function goes here
```

You see that `self` and `this` serve the same purpose.

An another point, you should use documentation! As in [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) the format recommanded is like:

```
def complex(real=0.0, imag=0.0):
    """Form a complex number.

    Keyword arguments:
    real -- the real part (default 0.0)
    imag -- the imaginary part (default 0.0)
    """
    if imag == 0.0 and real == 0.0:
        return complex_zero
    ...
        '''
```

Another thing, to follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it is better to write assignment and condition with a space after the operator.
Write  `items = []` or `self.index >= 0` instead of `items =[]` or `self.index >=0`.

Also you can drop `;` in Python, it's not Java :)

Edit: Also look at @Jon's comments below

Comment: Some other things, `items` should be an instance attribute and not a class one, `index` is redundant as you can do `len(items)` and then you're not manually carrying it about somewhere else, and the `pop` might as well use `items.pop(0)` and optionally catch the  exception and raise a more meaningful one - raising `Exception` is fairly broad... `peek` also doesn't seem to mirror its behaviour and returns `None`. Also - `if items` is sufficient for an empty check - no need to check its length there.

Comment: Some very good points!

Comment: (and `.append` instead of `.insert`) :)